# How can I convert java.util.Calendar to org.quartz.impl.calendar.DailyCalendar?

Tags: java, calendar, quartz-scheduler

I have two different calendars. I need to convert between  `java.util.Calendar` and `org.quartz.impl.calendar.DailyCalendar`. What is the best approach to do that?

Maybe there are some converters in Quartz library?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have two java.util.Calendars for each DailyCalendar, one that is set to the start time, and one that is set to the end time.

Converting from two java.util.Calendar objects to one DailyCalendar object:

```
java.util.Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - 360000); // an hour ago

java.util.Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); // now

DailyCalendar dc = new DailyCalendar(start.getTimeInMillis(), end.getTimeInMillis());
```

Converting back:

```
start.setTimeInMillis(dc.getTimeRangeStartingTimeInMillis());
end.setTimeInMillis(getTimeRangeEndingTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: `getTimeRangeStartingTimeInMillis` takes a `long timeInMillis`.

Comment: Doh; you're right. Mark, assuming the start and end times being set in DailyCalendar are private, you could try extending DailyCalendar and exposing those members with overridden public getters and setters in your new class.